# Centre div inside div using display: table

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```css
#innerLabels,
#innerFields {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.innerLabel {
  display: table;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
}
.innerLabel div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
#outterFields {
  background-color: red;
  width: 60%;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
#outterFields div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="outterFields">
  <div id="innerLabels">
    <div class="innerLabel">
      <div>hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't work out why the inner most div isn't being centred? I did look at some of the answers here regarding centring however I can't see what the problem is...[image]

I want the hello to be centred vertically to the centre but not horizontally.  **All other divs are positioned how I want them. There is no error in the other divs they are positioned side by side for a reason. The only change I want is the hello div moved vertically to the centre**

Comment: put text-align: center;

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hw9r5m51/ are you looking for this output?

Comment: not sure if that is what you are trying to achieve, but this is what I came up with: https://jsfiddle.net/jtjuh4mh/1/

Comment: http://codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/akwaVv  sorry I couldn't edit my comment above

Comment: All i want is the div enclosing the hello to be moved down to the middle thus vertically centring no change in the horizontal dimension.

Comment: Thanks mlegg but that's not what i want. I want the div moved only in the vertical axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just overiding your inner div with

```
#outterFields div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Just remove it or if you where intending a direct child do:

```
#outterFields > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
#innerLabels,
#innerFields {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.innerLabel {
  display: table;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
}
.innerLabel div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
#outterFields {
  background-color: red;
  width: 60%;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
#outterFields div {
 /* display: inline-block; */
}
```

```html
<div id="outterFields">
  <div id="innerLabels">
    <div class="innerLabel">
      <div>hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya it is, and this is  the correct answer,  **NOW** the OP explained what **really** wanted. unclear questions are not good at all

Comment: Oh $hit you're right! I thought the #outterFields div  selector was only direct children?!

Comment: I thought this was what you want, but I thought would be to basic that's why I approached with other way, but FYI to be direct children you had to use `>`

Comment: Thanks Dippas, sorry I'll try word the question better next time. Thanks for the help

Comment: Direct children is > will add it to my answer

Answer (score 1):

The necessary and most often sufficient condition where you can center a div using a `display: table-cell`, is as follows:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <div id="c">Helo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS as follows:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

#a {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#b {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#c {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

1. You need `html` and `body` elements to actually span the entire height of the document area if you want your `a` div to be able to make use of its `100%` height. If your use case demands height that does not depend on the height of the document body, you don't have to use the `body, html` selector.
2. When you use `display: table` the otherwise auto-expanding width for a `div` element (`width: auto` implicit rule) does not apply the same way anymore as elements with `display: table` use a conservative width calculation -- they only by default take as much space as the content requires. Since I am illustrating a "100% 100%" centering to you, I have `width: 100%` there to have the element expand to available parent width.
3. `height: 100%` is likewise needed to have the element expand to available parent height. It does not matter if its `display: block` as with regular `div` elements, or `display: table` -- you need to specify height if you want computed height that goes beyond content height.
4. The `display: table-cell` rule only works if there is an ancestor element with `display: table`, hence you need at least two elements inside one another to apply `display: table-cell` to the one that is contained in the other. You don't need to specify `height` because elements with `display: table-cell` occupy available parent height automatically.
5. `vertical-align` rule for the `display: table-cell` elements is the only case where the alignment applies to the *content* inside the element, as opposed to its usual behavior where it applies with regard to how the element is positioned within the parent. Meaning that in our case, the `vertical-align` tells the browser that everything contained in the element with `display: table-cell` is to be centered vertically within its computed height.
6. For the `c` element you would need `margin: auto` only if you had content that did not completely fill available parent width. Since `div` elements normally do, it is *not* necessary, but is forward thinking on my part -- in case you decide to use `span` or something else that computes its width conservatively. The `text-align` speaks for itself -- The anonymous textual content and text inside descendant elements, will be centered in the middle along horizontal axis.

Comment: Hi Amn I read your response thanks. I still don't know how to do what i want to do. Your example centres the element right in the middle. I'm still not sure how I can just vertically align a div within a div

Comment: Well, if it aligns the element right in the middle, is it not aligned vertically within a div?

Answer (score 1):

Your outterfields display inline block is overwriting other display items. I came up with better solution for you. I haven't used table but used flex here learn about flex it's more worth.

```css
#outterFields {
   background-color:red;
   width:60%;
   min-width:300px;
   height:300px;
}
#innerLabels, #innerFields {
   display:flex;
   align-items:center;
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
.innerLabel {
   display:flex;
   align-items:center;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   height:100px;
   width:80%;
}
.innerLabel div {
   display:table-cell; 
   vertical-align: middle;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="outterFields">
     <div id="innerLabels">
        <div class="innerLabel"><div>hello</div></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: apparently OP doesn't want that :/

Comment: Yeah OP doesn't want that but I gave him more precise solution than what he is doing bro.